# Python script not sending database log to server from crontab

Tags: python, json, cron

The issue is that when I execute the Python script normally from the terminal it is working fine but when the same file is being executed from the cron, there is no update at the server end.

File permissions have been set to 755. Earlier getting an error "No MTA installed, discarding output"; to solve that I use `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of my cron job. After that I get no error but still the issue remains the same. Also I have mentioned the environment on top of my python script.
configuration of cron is as follows:

```
* * * * * sudo python3 /home/pi/json_working/json_to_server_update.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: On making a log file from the cron i found that "os.path.isfile(filename)" is not working in the same manner as it is working on terminal. Although the file is present but the script running in cron "os.path.isfile(filename)" is returning false due to which file is not synced to the server. How to overcome this ?

Comment: Are you using a user crontab or the system crontab?  If you're using the system crontab, then when it runs the Python script, it will likely work with a different value for the `PATH` environment variable. Also, it'd be great if you could post your Python script (at least enough to attempt to reproduce your issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is solved now. I am using user crontab and i solved the issue by using os.path.isfile(os.path.join("path", "file name")) rather than os.path.isfile("path of file"). The latter one is actually a path and not a file so the output was always false and the sync was not made due to that. Now everything is working fine.